# How to perform padding separately for two column of content or image or text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the padding the make the left side text in center, while the right a bit above, but it's not working.

CSS:

```css
.container-fluid{
    padding: 3% 15%;
}
#title {
    background-color: black;
  }

  h1{
      
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 1.5;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 900;
  }

  /* Navigation Bar */
  .navbar{
padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }
  .navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-size: 2rem;
}


body{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Study Buddy</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--JavaScript Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--Bootstrap CSS and CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  <!--Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!--Font Awesome for Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c0ad3a43c4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="title">
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand ms-3" href=""><p class="logo">StudyBuddy </p></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler me-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mobile-navbar"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="mobile-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Find a study buddy to learn with.</h1>
        <button type="button"class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Learn More </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jLHT8lu.png" alt="gif" width="100%"height="auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I want it to be something like this? But I tried to add padding on top but it pushes the whole thing down, So do I make separate divisions or make a table in it? How to solve this?:
[image: Example]

Comment: Add `justify-content-center align-items-center` to the class `row` like `<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">` .. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ExvaOaL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `my-auto` with `col-6` for center content like:

```css
.container-fluid{
    padding: 3% 15%;
}
#title {
    background-color: black;
  }

  h1{
      
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 1.5;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 900;
  }

  /* Navigation Bar */
  .navbar{
padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }
  .navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-size: 2rem;
}


body{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Study Buddy</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--JavaScript Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--Bootstrap CSS and CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  <!--Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!--Font Awesome for Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c0ad3a43c4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="title">
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand ms-3" href=""><p class="logo">StudyBuddy </p></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler me-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mobile-navbar"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="mobile-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto">
        <h1>Find a study buddy to learn with.</h1>
        <button type="button"class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Learn More </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jLHT8lu.png" alt="gif" width="100%"height="auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

- [Spacing bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/)